# react-tabs not styled as tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tabs

Just trying to get a basic example of react-tabs working.  The styling seems to be missing.  The example below is in code sandbox (look in 'Hello.js'), but I see exactly the same behavior after installing the package into my project via npm. What am I missing?  Thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/jzql1q6819

Comment: side note: you can collapse all of the separate import statements to react-tabs to `import { Tabs, TabList, Tab, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';`

Comment: good point, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs at https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs#styling

> react-tabs does not include any style loading by default. Default stylesheets are provided and can be included in your application if desired.

You will have to import the styles yourself. I don't think Code Sandbox will let you import them directly from the NPM package, so you will have to use a CDN or other source.

Besides that, the tabs are working in your example. Clicking a list item reveals different content

Here is a fork of your example with the styles added: https://codesandbox.io/s/ym7l2zk4oj